# $|px^2+qx+r|\le1$ for all $x$ in $[-1; 1]$, show that $|rx^2+qx+p|\le2$ for all $x$ in $[-1; 1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, absolute-value

I have an interesting problem, in which i would be utmost happy to receive some help:

$p$, $q$, $r$ are real numbers with the following property: $|px^2+qx+r|\le 1$ for all $x$ in $[-1; 1]$. Prove that $|rx^2+qx+p|\le2$ for all $x$ in $[-1; 1]$.

Substituting for $x=0$ yields $-1\le r\le1$.
$x=1$ and $x=-1$ results $-1\le p+q+r\le1$ and $-1\le p-q+r\le 1$ respectively.
From those: $-2\le p\le2$ and $-1\le q\le 1$.

I couldn't go anything further. Would be happy to receive some ideas. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $P(x)=px^2+qx+r$ and $P_1(x)=rx^2+qx+p$.

W.L.O.G. we can assume $p\geq0$ because if not then we can consider $-P(x)=-(px^2+qx+r)$ satisfying all the given conditions and here the the leading coef. of $x^2$ is +ve.

W.L.O.G. we can also consider $q\geq0$ beacuse if not then we can talk abt $P(-x)$ satisfying all the given conditions.

Now putting  $x=1,0,-1$ in turn we get,

$|p+q+r|\leq1,|r|\leq1,|p-q+r|\le1$

From this applying $\Delta$ inequalities we get,

$|r|\leq1,|p+q|\leq2,|p-q|\le2$

And further if $r\geq0$ then we have for $|x|\le1$,

$P_1(x)=rx^2+qx+p\leq r+q+p\le 1$  and $P_1(x)=rx^2+qx+p\geq 0+q(-1)+p\ge -2$

So it follws that $|P_1(x)|\leq 2$

Now if $r\leq 0$ then we have for $|x|\le1$,

$P_1(x)=rx^2+qx+p\leq 0+q+p\leq 2$ and $p_1(x)\ge r+q(-1)+p\ge p-q+r\ge-1$

So in this case also we have $|P_1(x)|\leq 2$

So we are done.