# If $|ax^2+bx+c|\le1$ for $|x|\le1$(redundant?), then prove that $|cx^2+bx+a|\le2$ for $|x|\le1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

If $|ax^2+bx+c|\le1$ for $|x|\le1$, then prove that $|cx^2+bx+a|\le2$ for $|x|\le1$. $a,b,c$ are real.

I discovered this to be a duplicate of [$|px^2+qx+r|\le1$ for all $x$ in $[-1; 1]$, show that $|rx^2+qx+p|\le2$ for all $x$ in $[-1; 1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310199/px2qxr-le1-for-all-x-in-1-1-show-that-rx2qxp-le2-for-all)

With reference to the answer there , is the information $|x|\le1$ redundant as the proof only uses the conditions at $x=1,0,-1$

Comment: I will return to prove it to you, now is bed time....